# How do I get the user role from the database after it checks for its username and password

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I have a basic login function, where if the user clicks the login button after entering the user and password, it fetch from the database and check if the username and password is correct and display it to the admin jframe, but I want to display the jframe according to the user type. Eg. Admin, gets Admin Jframe, customer get customer jframe. In this case, Admin = 1, customer = 2 and etc, so how do I check the userRole from the database and display their respective jframe?

I have try to look up for tutorial on how to do it, but all I found are basic tutorials which doesn't involve getting the userType/Role

```
public boolean isLogin(String user, String pass) throws Exception{
        PreparedStatement pr = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Login where username = ? and password = ?";

        try{
            pr = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pr.setString(1, user);
            pr.setString(2, pass);

            rs = pr.executeQuery();

             if(rs.next()){
             return true;   
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            return false;
        }

        finally{
                pr.close();
                rs.close();
        }

    }
```

**Login Controller**

```
@FXML
    public void Login (ActionEvent event){
        try{

            if(this.loginModel.isLogin(this.username.getText(), this.password.getText())){


                Stage stage = (Stage) this.login.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();

                adminLogin();

            }
             else{
                this.loginStatus.setText("The username or password entered is incorrect. Please check and try again.");
            }
        }           
        catch(Exception localException){

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know you DB scheme, but you are getting all(`SELECT *`) the data from the `Login` table. If the `role` is in that table just do something like `rs.getString('role');`

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle user authorization in my apps:

- Create table in database for users, with name authorization of type
  int()
- Set value of authorization from 0 (or 1) for users, and +1 for each
  authorization you want to add (analyzer, admin etc).
- In login when you get validation data (check if given name + password
  is correct) also get its authorization.
- Store your current user locally.
- Based on validation you can redirect to according stage (window) or
  just make those "options" in your app available by checking if user has necessary authorization.
- In your user managing window, when editing or adding new user, set
  option to choose authorization.

Hope it helps you !

Comment: @User2382 in which part you are having difficulties? The idea was to add another property in User object (and in user table in database), and by checking **if(user.getAuthorization() == 1){ ... } else { ... }** you can choose in which stage to redirect. It's up to you to choose how to structure your code depending on your app.

Comment: Well I would say the whole things, since im really weak in programming, but I'll see what I can do